# Resting Form and Clear Error Validations in register form on clicking a button

Tags: angularjs

I am doing one register page using `angularjs`.

Follows my `html` code:

```
    <form name="frominline" action="post" class="clearfix form-hidden" id="Register-form">
                                 <div class="col-md-12">

                                    <div class="input-group blmd-form">
                                        <div class="blmd-line">
                                            <input type="text" name="userid" autocomplete="off" id="username" class="form-control" required autofocus="" ng-model="user.name"  ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="12" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }">
                                            <label class="blmd-label">User Id</label>
                                        </div>

                                         <p   class="login-error" ng-show="frominline.userid.$dirty && frominline.userid.$error.required">
                                                <span style="color : red">required</span>
                                          </p>

                                          <p ng-show="frominline.userid.$error.minlength" class="help-block" style="color:red;">Username is too short.</p>
                                          <p ng-show="frominline.userid.$error.maxlength" class="help-block" style="color:red;">Username is too long.</p>
                                    </div>
                                       <div class="input-group blmd-form">
                                        <div class="blmd-line">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" id="email" class="form-control" required autofocus="" ng-model="user.email">
                                            <label class="blmd-label">Email</label>

                                        </div>
                                         <span class="login-error" ng-show="frominline.email.$error.required && frominline.email.$dirty" style="color:red;" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }">required</span>
                                            <span  class="login-error" ng-show="!frominline.email.$error.required && frominline.email.$error.email && frominline.email.$dirty" style="color:red;">invalid email</span>
                                </div>
<button type="reset" ng-click="resetform(frominline)">reset</button>
    </form>

My js code:
app.controller('loginCtrl'['$scope',function('$scope'){
 var user = this;
$scope.resetform(form){
user.name='';
user.email='';
    $scope.frominline.$dirty = false;
    $scope.frominline.$pristine = true;
    $scope.frominline.$submitted = false;
}]);
```

Now, in first image, those are the validation errors.
Now, I hit the reset button and the validation errors are gone but in the second image I got required field.

Can you please help me removing or reseting the whole form on a button click?

I tried with many options like `$setPristine()` or `$setValidity()` but i can't fix this issue "required" error message.

Follows the image of the form with only required error message after clicking reset button:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The form is probably cleared, but those input fields are not. When you are display the error for a particular field (e.g. `ng-show="frominline.userid.$error.minlength"`) include the state of the form as well (e.g. `ng-show="frominline.$submitted && frominline.userid.$error.minlength"`).

Comment: Great! Do not forget to accept the answer so others can find it easily. ;)

Comment: hey but required error message is not showing now i want both to display

Comment: for example when user enter something and when he clear the input field i want to show required as error message and after clicking the reset button i want to reset the form as before

Comment: Error messages will show after the user will try to submit the form. Otherwise you would have to loop through all your inputs and set their `$touched` property to false. Then you could change `frominline.$submitted` to `frominline.INPUT_NAME.$touched`.